# Workbox Background Sync CORS

Tags: cors, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox, background-sync

I'm using Workbox using the [background sync plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync). Unfortunately the plugin did not run as expected for my application, which relies on a CORS request.

My app first sends an options preflight request to ensure that the request is allowed, and then the real request is sent.

The problem is that when i go offline, the preflight request fails and crashes my app before my actual request has a chance to be saved in IndexDb and replayed later.

How can i solve this?

I am currently configuring my background sync as suggested in the documentation, but with a cross-origin endpoint, like so:

```js
    const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', {
      maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
    });

    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      new RegExp("https://my-api.example.com/api/add"),
      workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
        plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
      }),
      'POST'
    );
```

taken from here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync

I wonder if I should be adding the `OPTIONS` requests to IndexDB as well?

```js
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      new RegExp("https://my-api.example.com/api/add"),
      workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
        plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
      }),
      'OPTIONS'
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @ricardogunawan! Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem  Also, I made some minor edits to help clarify your question, I hope that's ok.

Comment: no use yet. in the end i delete this function from my app. hope some fix in this feature.